# How to import xml-files to Excel in active workbook with individual worksheets in excel with the name of the XML-file for each folder?

Tags: excel, xml, vba

I need to rename folders/sheets when importing several xml-files to excel. I would prefer the names to be Data1, Data2,... etc. If this is not possible, the names could be the same as the imported xml-files.

The code I am using works fine to import the xml-files to individual sheets in the active workbook.

```
Sub From_XML_To_XL()
Dim xmlWb As Workbook, xSWb As Workbook, xStrPath$, xfdial As FileDialog, xFile$
Set xfdial = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
xfdial.AllowMultiSelect = False
xfdial.Title = "Select a folder"
If xfdial.Show = -1 Then xStrPath = xfdial.SelectedItems(1) & "\"
If xStrPath = "" Then Exit Sub
Set xSWb = ThisWorkbook
xFile = Dir(xStrPath & "\*.xml")
Do While xFile <> ""
    Set xmlWb = Workbooks.OpenXML(xStrPath & "" & xFile)
    xSWb.Sheets.Add , xSWb.Worksheets(xSWb.Worksheets.Count)
    xmlWb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Copy xSWb.Sheets(xSWb.Worksheets.Count).Cells(1, 1)
    MsgBox xmlWb.Name & " copied to " & xSWb.Sheets(xSWb.Worksheets.Count).Name
    xmlWb.Close False
    xFile = Dir()
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
xSWb.Save
MsgBox "End of code."
Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
MsgBox "Error!", , "Kutools for Excel"
End Sub
```

Comment: Be careful when using Sheets versus Worksheets as Sheets will include Chart sheets whereas Worksheets will not. When that is sorted simply name the last sheet each time in the loop using "Data" & cstr(counter) where counter is a Long variable you increment in the loop.

Comment: Thank you for helping me QHarr! Could you edit my code directly to show what you mean. I will give you credit for this if it works:)

Comment: Something like this? https://pastebin.com/t9zdhpgs

Comment: Didn't work. Received an error message: Run-Time error 9 - subscript out of range

Comment: On which line did error occur please?

Comment: Set xmlWb = Workbooks.OpenXML(xStrPath & "" & xFile)
        xSWb.Worksheets.Add , xSWb.Worksheets(xSWb.Worksheets.Count)

Comment: What if we edit the code to paste the first xm-file in an existing tab named Data1, and the next in Data2 etc? probably easier?

Comment: that is two lines. Which of the two lines is causing the fail?